# Can't read the function $f_n(x) = x^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have this question but I can't figure out what the function does.

If $n$ is a positive integer, we define the function $f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by the formula

$$f_n(x) = x^n.$$

For which positive integers $n$ is this function injective? For which positive
integers $n$ is this function surjective?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Your functions yields something like this: $f_{1}=x$, $f_{2}=x^{2}$

Comment: I haven't tried anything really. If I make $n=2$ for instance, I get $x^2$ back I guess, but I don't understand how this tells me anything about injectivity.

Comment: Try answering if $n=3$ and then if $n=2$.

Comment: @RyanTandy well, is the function $f_2(x) = x^2$ injective?

Comment: A little googling might help @Ryan Tandy . It is a pretty easy topic but requires a little information about definition of functions.

Comment: Oh right I see now, thankyou.

Comment: A link for you @RyanTandy : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, then for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$ there is at most one $x \in \mathbb{R}$ giving $y = x^{n}$; if $n$ is even, then $y = 2$ gives $y = x^{n}$ for $x = y^{1/n}, -y^{1/n}$. So $n$ odd implies $f_{n}$ is injective; and $n$ even implies $f_{n}$ is not injective.

Only for odd $n$ is $f_{n}$ surjective. If $n$ is odd, then $y \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $y = x^{n}$ for some $x$, i.e. $x = (y)^{1/n}$. If $n$ is even, then $y=-2$ gives $y \neq x^{n}$ for all $x$.

Comment: Typo corrected :).